# How to validate Array length using Ruby's Grape?

Tags: ruby, ruby-grape

I have an array of items and want to ensure that it has **at least one item** but **not more than two.** (a kind of values range). Does Grape propose any elegant way to solve the length validation issue?

Currently I have structure like this.

```
params do
  requires :items, type Array[String] # ???
end
```

I'm thinking about writing **a class with custom validation** which receives max and min values and compare them with array length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an example explaining how to do this in the [Grape README](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape#custom-validators):

```
class Length < Grape::Validations::Base
  def validate_param!(attr_name, params)
    unless params[attr_name].length <= @option
      fail Grape::Exceptions::Validation, params: [@scope.full_name(attr_name)], message: "must be at the most #{@option} characters long"
    end
  end
end
```

You can make it work the way you expect with something like this for the max length of the array:

```
class MaxLength < Grape::Validations::Base
  def validate_param!(attr_name, params)
    unless params[attr_name].length <= @option
      fail Grape::Exceptions::Validation, 
      params: [attr_name.to_s],
      message: "must be at the most #{@option} elements long"
    end
  end
end
```

And this for the min length of the array:

```
class MinLength < Grape::Validations::Base
  def validate_param!(attr_name, params)
    unless params[attr_name].length >= @option
      fail Grape::Exceptions::Validation, 
      params: [attr_name.to_s],
      message: "must be at the least #{@option} elements long"
    end
  end
end
```

Then call it:

```
params do
  requires :array, type: Array, min_length: 1, max_length: 2, desc: 'Array with defined length'
end
```